# Restricting EMS cliemt connections

Tags: tibco, tibco-ems

Hi Our EMS server is used by other clients for putting message. But some time they dont close connections and number of connections is reaching maximum limit of the server. Is there any way where we can restrict the number of connections for the client based on emsusername provided to the client or based on the host name from where client is creating connection. Is there any configuration we can do for client specific connections restriction.

Comment: Isn't there anything like connection expiration after some idle time?

Comment: no I have manually deleted connections for each connection id. Please share if any configuration is there based on idle time which we can do on ems server.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such provision in EMS server or client libraries where you can restrict the number of consumer/producer clients based on their user names or other properties. You can have a look at the JAAS and JACI provision supported by EMS which can be used to write your own JAVA authentication custom modules which run in JVM within EMS server. You can find more information about JAAS and JACI on Oracles documentation site.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the *server_timeout_client_connection* setting ?

From the doc :

> server_timeout_client_connection = limit
>
> In a server-to-client connection, if the server does not receive a heartbeat for a
>   period exceeding this limit (in seconds), it closes the connection.
>   We recommend setting this value to approximately 3 times the heartbeat interval, as it is specified in *client_heartbeat_server*.
>
> Zero is a special value, which disables heartbeat detection in the server (although
>   clients still send heartbeats).